# How to add Google Column Chart and Google Table Chart in the same page?

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I am trying to add a google column chart followed by a google table chart in the same page. While adding the column chart it works fine, but as soon as I add the Table chart I get an error in the code of the google column chart. The error is :
You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView.

The interesting part is when I remove the line which gives the link to the javascript file which is needed for the Google Table chart, then this error goes away. The line is :

Below is my code, can anyone please help me with the solution of how to add a google column chart and google table chart in the same page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MyTitle</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- FontAwesome Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Custom Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- Google Fonts-->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart', 'table', 'bar']}]}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);


      function drawChart1() {
      var abc = $.ajax({url:'kpi24.php',async:false,dataType:"json",}).responseText;
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(abc);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: '',
            subtitle: '',
          },
          bars: 'vertical',
          vAxis: {format: 'percent'},
          legend: { position: 'right', maxLines: 3 },
          colors: ['#20488D', '#EA922B']
        };

       var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));


        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
      var abcnew = $.ajax({url:'kpi26.php',async:false,dataType:"json",}).responseText;
        var datanew = new google.visualization.DataTable(abcnew);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(datanew, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }

</script>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- /. NAV SIDE  -->


                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Top 5 Doctors 

                            </div> 
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 1200px; height: 300px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Doctors by Hospital Revenue


                            </div> 
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <div id="table_div"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>





                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
                </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
            </div>
         <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
        </div>
     <!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
    <!-- JS Scripts-->
    <!-- jQuery Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
      <!-- Custom Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom-scripts.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`google` is loaded too many times.
`google.load` and `google.setOnLoadCallback` should only be called once.

The packages needed for a Material Column chart and a Table chart are `bar` and `table`.

Here, I've removed the two `autoload` scripts and draw the Table chart after the Column chart.

Also, I would recommend adding the `<script>` tags to either the `<head>` or `<body>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>MyTitle</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Styles-->
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- FontAwesome Styles-->
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Custom Styles-->
  <link href="assets/css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Google Fonts-->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar", "table"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

    function drawChart1() {
      var abc = $.ajax({url:'kpi24.php',async:false,dataType:"json",}).responseText;
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(abc);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: '',
          subtitle: '',
        },
        bars: 'vertical',
        vAxis: {format: 'percent'},
        legend: { position: 'right', maxLines: 3 },
        colors: ['#20488D', '#EA922B']
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

      // draw table chart
      drawTable();
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawTable() {
      var abcnew = $.ajax({url:'kpi26.php',async:false,dataType:"json",}).responseText;
      var datanew = new google.visualization.DataTable(abcnew);
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
      table.draw(datanew, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: You don't need to load the www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js if you are not using it.  If you want to use it, you'll need to change your google.load() and google.setOnLoadCallback() calls.  See the docs here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#basic-library-loading